# How to re-use the same itemprocessor in multiple steps (each containing a different itemreader) in a Spring Batch job

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am setting up a new batch job to create an extract file.  I am using multiple sql queries (each using their own custom itemreader) to grab a variety of results from a db. What is the best way to process and combine/write these results into a single file for output? Do I need to create a new processor for each step? Or is there something more efficient?

I am seeing CompositeItemProcessor, but it seems that it would be used to chain multiple processes together in a single step instead of being used in multiple steps.

Answer (score 0):

A chunk oriented step can have only one reader, so if you want to read items from different sources and combine them, you would need multiple steps. In your case, I would proceed in two phases:

- Phase 1: several steps reading data from different sources and writing it in a temporary storage (an intermediate table for example). There is probably no need for an item processor here. These steps can run in parallel
- Phase 2: a chunk-oriented step reads data from the temporary storage, process data (by combining fields or doing any business logic) and write results in a consolidated output

Hope this helps.